# ordinal arithmetic: help needed in understanding this proof (3 simple equations)

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I am reading through this book: st.openlogicproject.org.
Currently stuck on Lemma 13.6. on page 178.
I want to apologize for using an image instead of typing it down, for some users can't read it then. I'll try to give the details soon if there is any need, and hope that access through the link is sufficient for you now.
[image]

For the proof of the first statement it seems as if $0 \times \{1\} = \{0\}$. Or why is that equal, then? (Zero is the empty set, I suppose.)

Similarly, in the second statement, I can follow only the first line.

For the last case, the limit case, my understanding is also totally unclear. At the moment only very few aspects of it make a little bit of sense to me.

As always, also short hints and suggestions are appreciated..
Thank you for reading!

:)

**EDIT:** Following definitions are applied:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful, if you could give the definitions of relevant notions used in your post. I assume that the book you use introduces ordinal addition via a 2-place operation on partial orders that preserves well-ordering. The operation typically employed in such an approach takes isomorphic copies of partial orders $P, Q$ and sets them side by side, every element of $P$ preceding every element of $Q$.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I will think about it as soon as I have some time and then tell if I succeded...I will also post an explanation of the definitions...but, if I understand you correctly, yes, that is the approach taken in this resource..

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Isomorphic well-orderings have the same order type. So what you have to show in the base case is that the well-ordering $(\alpha \times \{0\} \cup 0 \times \{ 1\}, <)$ is isomorphic to the well ordering $(\alpha \times \{0\} \cup \{0\}, <)$. Analogously for the successor case.

Comment: I see the isomorphism between $\alpha$ and $\alpha \times {0}$, but insn't $0 \times \{1\}$ the empty set, and thus the brackets '{' and '}' on the second zero in $(\alpha \times \{0\} \cup \{0\}, <)$ incorrect/a typo? Also, concerning the successor case, it's not difficult to map $(\alpha \times \{0\} \cup \beta^+ \times \{ 1\})$ to $(\alpha \times \{0\} \cup \beta \times \{ 1\}) \cup {\emptyset}$ isomorphically, and one has the impression that this suffices, still I can't clearly see how the implies the desired equation, although of course isomorphic well orders have the same order type.

Comment: As for the limit case, I can accept it a bit more now. But especially I fail to understand the 'moreover'-sentence in the last two lines.